# Find all current files that Ruby opened when running a program

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

This is someone of an esoteric request, and is just of theoretical interest to me (In other words, I am not used this in production code). I'd like to know if it is possible to figure out all the files involved when running a ruby program. That is, files `require`d by said program during its execution (or involved some other way, such as `autoload`ed by Rails midway through the program).

I know that one can use `ObjectSpace` and loop through the object, excluding all but `File` and its descendants, and I had partial success with this method when I disable garbage collection (otherwise the list shrinks at random times, understandably). However, doing this at the start of the program ignores those files that are required in the middle of it, so I can run the same code at the end, and get the union of said files?

Comment: One thing to try is patching out the `require` function with one that logs, but keep in mind there are a number of ways to load in Ruby code: `load`, `autoload`, `require_relative` among others. You might have more success with wrapping Ruby in a debugger and watching for file I/O events.

Comment: to find all dependencies of a gem (but not all files) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108109/how-do-i-find-out-all-the-dependencies-of-a-gem

Answer (score 3):

I did exactly the same a couple months ago. Here is my dirty little program:

```
REQUIRE_FILE = ENV.fetch('REQUIRE_FILE', '/tmp/requires.txt')

File.open(REQUIRE_FILE, 'w')

Kernel.module_eval do
  alias_method :require_without_benchmark, :require

  def require(name)
    start = Time.now
    begin
      require_without_benchmark(name)
    ensure
      time = Time.now - start
      File.write(REQUIRE_FILE, [name, time.to_f].join(',').concat("\n"), mode: 'a')
    end
  end
end
```

Then run your program as:

```
ruby -r ./require-benchmark.rb program.rb
```

Comment: This is neat. It would be even better if it could print the absolute path of each file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

## lsof

On linux, you could use [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) :

```
puts `lsof -a -p #{Process.pid}`
```

It gives you the files **held** open by the current process.

The list is far from being complete, though : Once this line executes, many files have been read, parsed, executed and closed.

When `lsof` scans for open files, they don't appear in the list anymore.

## strace

[`strace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (also on Linux) is a great tool for what you want to achieve (see this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58887/how-do-i-monitor-opened-files-of-a-process-in-realtime)). It will give a lot (possibly way too much) information :

```
strace -e trace=open -o opened_files.txt ruby hello_world.rb
#=> Hello world
```

`opened_files.txt` now begins with :

```
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/tls/x86_64/libruby.so.2.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/tls/libruby.so.2.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/x86_64/libruby.so.2.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libruby.so.2.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
....
```

It has 571 lines for a "Hello World" script and 112302 (!) for a "rails runner hello_world.rb" script.

The output file has many "ENOENT (No such file or directory)" lines, so you might want to parse and filter it.

For macOS and other *nix, there should be [`dtrace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).

Comment: A lot of these files are opened only briefly, so catching them in `lsof` may prove futile. It's good for seeing what's held open, though.

Comment: `strace` and `dtrace` are really great tools. Much better call! I've also had luck with [`fs_usage`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) for macOS/OS X.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I get a list of files that have been `required` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190015/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-that-have-been-required-in-ruby) for required files.
For all the dependencies of a gem see [How do I find out all the dependencies of a gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108109/how-do-i-find-out-all-the-dependencies-of-a-gem)

The constant `$LOADED_FEATURES` holds an array of all files with paths that are loaded with a require, not just the gems themselves but all files involved.
Try `$LOADED_FEATURES.dup.uniq` at the end of your script.

For the normal files opened by File you could overwrite `IO.open` and/or `File.open` and sister methods read, binread etc in the way KARASZI shows in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by KARAZI, here is a version that displayes the file's path:

```
REQUIRE_FILE = ENV.fetch('REQUIRE_FILE', '/tmp/requires.txt')

File.open(REQUIRE_FILE, 'w')

Kernel.module_eval do

  alias_method :require_without_benchmark, :require

  def require(name)
    start = Time.now
    begin
      require_without_benchmark(name)
    ensure
      time = Time.now - start
      path = ''
      $:.each do |p|
        if File.exists? File.join(p, name)
          path = File.join(p, name)
          break
        end
      end
      File.write(REQUIRE_FILE, [name, path, time.to_f].join(',').concat("\n"), mode: 'a')
    end
  end
end
```

Then run your program as:

```
ruby -r ./require-benchmark.rb program.rb
```